# Game Center in tvOS not showing up

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-center, tvos

I currently have Game Center working in my iOS target, but not working in the tvOS target.

I've already added the Leaderboard images and placed the identifier in Xcode here:

[image]

This is the class that I'm using to bring up the leaderboard and initiate the player. It's called GameKitHelper.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import GameKit

let PresentAuthenticationViewController = "PresentAuthenticationViewController"

class GameKitHelper: NSObject {

  static let sharedInstance = GameKitHelper()


  var authenticationViewController: UIViewController?
  var gameCenterEnabled = false

  func authenticateLocalPlayer() {

    //1
    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) in

        if viewController != nil {
            //2
            self.authenticationViewController = viewController

                 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(PresentAuthenticationViewController, object: self)
        } 
    else if error == nil {
            //3
            self.gameCenterEnabled = true
        }
    }

 }

 func reportAchievements(achievements: [GKAchievement], errorHandler: ((NSError?)->Void)? = nil) {
    guard gameCenterEnabled else {
        return
    }

    GKAchievement.reportAchievements(achievements, withCompletionHandler: errorHandler)
 }

 func showGKGameCenterViewController(viewController: UIViewController) {
    guard gameCenterEnabled else {
        return
    }

    //1
    let gameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()

    //2
    gameCenterViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self

    //3
    viewController.presentViewController(gameCenterViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

   func saveHighScore(identifier: String, score: Int) {

     if (GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated) {

        let scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: identifier)
        scoreReporter.value = Int64(score)

        let scoreArray:[GKScore] = [scoreReporter]

        GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {

            error -> Void in

            if (error != nil) {

                print("error")
            }
            else {

                print("Posted score of \(score)")
            }
        })
    }
  }
 }

extension GameKitHelper: GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {
  func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController:   GKGameCenterViewController) {
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
 }
}
```

NavigationController class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                            selector: Selector("showAuthenticationViewController"),
                                                name: PresentAuthenticationViewController,
                                              object: nil)
    GameKitHelper.sharedInstance.authenticateLocalPlayer()
 }

 func showAuthenticationViewController() {
    let gameKitHelper = GameKitHelper.sharedInstance

    if let authenticationViewController = gameKitHelper.authenticationViewController {
        topViewController?.presentViewController(authenticationViewController,
                                                animated: true,
                                              completion: nil)
     }
  }


  deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
  }
```

Comment: Can you add a little bit more information? Have you checked that the user initialisation was successful and gameCenterEnabled is true?

Comment: @Stefan Check the `func authenticateLocalPlayer()` . Also, I have another class that runs some Game Center code, but I'm pretty sure the class I posted is the main class. Like I said, this works fine in iOS. I'm even able to post high scores to it, but not on tvOS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an "Apple TV Dashboard Image" in your app's asset catalog. The dashboard artwork should be 923x150 with transparency, and it doesn't need to be layered since the user can't select it.

The [tvOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/) claim that the dashboard artwork is optional, but in my experience `GKGameCenterViewController` will refuse to appear if you don't have one.